# iOS 7 Sprite Kit frame rate

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I have written the -update method for an SKScene in two different forms and one has a much better and constant frame rate than the other.

Can someone explain the difference between the two implementations and reason(s) why they create two different frame rates?

```
Method 1 (frame rate drops to about 20-30 fps when moving sprite)

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime

    {
        [self updateBackground];
        player.position = CGPointMake(slider.sliderValue * self.view.frame.size.width/200 + self.view.frame.size.width/2, player.position.y);
    }


Method 2 (frame rate remains constant 60 fps when moving sprite)

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
    {
        [self updateBackground];
        delta = currentTime - previousTime;
        previousTime = currentTime;
        //NSLog(@"%f",delta);
        player.position = CGPointMake(delta * adjustmentFactor * slider.sliderValue * self.view.frame.size.width/200 + self.view.frame.size.width/2, player.position.y);
    }
```

Comment: The `[self updateBackground]` may be slow. Try taking it out to see if that makes it better.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have tested it with and without [self updateBackground] results are identical.

Comment: I think something else is going on outside of this code. Is delta being used elsewhere in the code ? Perhaps if delta is not being calculated something undesirable happens.

Comment: are you testing on a device, preferably confirming the behavior with a release build?

Comment: yes, I am testing it on a device.

Comment: There is no reason those should yield a different framerate.
My guess is there's something else going on outside this loop which differs between method 1 and method 2.
One approach to writing a test like this would be to put both versions of the code in the same update() routine, and switch between them based on a static bool, and then use a breakpoint to change the value of the bool.  eg:
`static bool useMethod1 = true;
if (useMethod1) {
   // method 1
} else {
   // method 2
}`

Comment: are you sure your frame rate is not dropping in the second function,it looks like your guy is frame skipping with that map, so you may not notice it (not sure if you have the FPS showing on screen)